# Symfony2: prod cannot find /login

Tags: php, symfony

In a practice run for a possible VPS solution as an alternative to a failing shared host environment I've installed an application on a Ubuntu 12.10 virtual machine on my Windows box.  The dev environment behaves properly.  Yet after

```
projectmana@ubuntu:~/www2.projectmana.org$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
projectmana@ubuntu:~/www2.projectmana.org$ chmod -R 777 app/cache/prod
```

I continue to see this in the apache error log:

> File does not exist:
>   /home/projectmana/www2.projectmana.org/htdocs/login

The route certainly exists or dev would not let me log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you have mod_rewrite (a2enmod rewrite) and if your virtualhost has the `AllowOverride All` option (in order to enable .htaccess)